# Recommend issue tracker to be used with Basecamp

Tags: web-application, defect-tracking, bugzilla

### Background

In my company we started to use [Basecamp](http://basecamp.com) for managing the project (mainly assigning work to developers). But unfortunately Basecamp on it's own doesn't have sufficient tools to track the bugs (the bug reports look like fairy tales missing crucial information).

I myself favor **ClearQuest** for bug tracking as a compromise between easy to use and feature richness.

### Options - I found

I looked around for what can be used (integrates) with basecamp and found following:

> 1. [Zappier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/github/basecamp/71/github-issue-basecamp-todo/)
>
>    - good as we already use guithub
> 2. Basecamp Integrations
>
>    - [BugHerd](http://basecamp.com/extras#development)
>    - [Donedone](http://www.getdonedone.com/tour/)
>    - [BugDigger](http://bugdigger.com/tour/)
> 3. Use a general issue tracker with 0 basecamp inter-operation (E.g. Bugzilla)
> 4. Write our own using basecamp API (who has time for that?)

1 and 2 are generally 15-30 USD per month for the minimalistic account. I'd prefer something for free.

### The question

Do you have any other recommendation?
Do you have experience with tools mentioned in 1 and 2?

We are small team (less than 10 persons). 100 issues shall be enough.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Basecamp and Jira separately, and Zapier seems to integrate both of those.

They also have a free subscription [here](https://zapier.com/app/pricing)

Fairly straightforward information here:
[Integrate Basecamp with JIRA](https://zapier.com/zapbook/basecamp/jira/)

If you find that your team is growing, or you need to integrate more issues you can always just subscribe to a higher tier.

+1 for Zapier

Comment: Yes, **Zapier** has sthg for free. But **JIRA** is not for free, and if I understand well, you also need **Greenhopper** (which is an additional cost).